# History of rails script/generate commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there a plugin/gem to log/record the history of rails script/generate commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added code to script/generate and that does the trick.

```
CMD = "#{$0} #{ARGV.join(' ')}\n"
File.open(File.expand_path('../../log/generate.log',
         __FILE__), 'a') {|f| f.write(CMD) }
```