# Write code that fires on "generate" commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, listener, execute

In which file in Rails do I need to place code that I want executed for example when the user types

```
rails g migration doSomethingFancy
```

My intention is to keep track of these commands in a sort-of log file. I noticed [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945054/history-of-rails-script-generate-commands), but it seems this method has been deprecated in Rails3 (creating a generate file doesn't work). Do you know of any way to achieve a similar result in Rails3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could certainly do something similar by editing the `rails` script file.

```
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

# This is the logging code
CMD = "#{$0} #{ARGV.join(' ')}\n"
File.open('/absolute-path/log/generate.log', 'a') {|f| f.write(CMD) }

gem 'rails', version
load Gem.bin_path('rails', 'rails', version)
```